# Use Safari Technology Preview with a different "profile"

Tags: mac, safari

Is there a way to run Safari Technology Preview using a different "profile"?
Like loading a different `Library`

For work (and development) reason I would need to run Safari and Safari TP like they were not sharing any data: cookies, bookmarks, history etc.

Comment: Create a new user account and enable fast user switching :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.
I've yet to find any way of doing this with Safari.

You can Safari Technology Preview as 2nd browser instance. 
But it will have all settings, history, etc. as your main Safari.

In macOS Monterey, you can also use tabs groups and hotkey  Opt + Command + Arrow Up/Down to quickly switch.

But if you want to actually have 2 real, completely separate users you either use a second browser (like Chrome) or create 2 macOS user-profiles and switch between them.